# Any input as to what to study in order to work into genetic engineering from math background?

Tags: statistics, molecular-genetics

Any input as to what to study in order to work into genetic engineering from math background?

I have troubles understanding what the "interface" would be between mathematicians and biologists/biotechnologists.

Wikipedia links the first model of an organism having built in 2011:

https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Computational_genomics#First_Computer_Model_of_an_Organism

And it based on statistically analyzing biology/chemistry papers. This reminds of a typical "stats research". So there's not necessarily direct interaction between the empirical and the formal. However, for new applications, it's given that there must be some interaction, in order to synthesize knowledge?

Comment: I don't understand the question. Do you seek advice to how to proceed in your career or do you want to know how does an "empirical" and a a "formal" science interact?